# Angular2: How can i iterate each object to an observable containing object array data?

Tags: angular, observable

Hi guys i am just starting to learn(upgrade to be specific) Angular 2, i just have some few questions. how do i iterate each object in the observable of array object?

this is what i retrieve if i go get data from "api/v1/example" already postman on this and yes its working. .

```
// my arrayObject
[
{
    "userID": 12,
    "username": "admin1",
    "password": "admin2"
},
{
    "userID": 13,
    "username": "admin21",
    "password": "admin32"
},
{
    "userID": 14,
    "username": "admin221",
    "password": "admin72"
},
{
    "userID": 15,
    "username": "admin451",
    "password": "admin652"
},
{
    "userID": 16,
    "username": "admin561",
    "password": "admin1222"
},
{
    "userID": 17,
    "username": "admin154",
    "password": "admin572"
},
{
    "userID": 127,
    "username": "admin1254",
    "password": "admin5721"
}
]
```

So as what i said before i'm just learning angular 2, so i tried to use this dummy data to test observable, but somehow in my codes i can't really iterate each data in the object, this is what i tried so far

```
 myData: Any[];

 constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

 ngOnInit() {
     this._http.get<Any[]>("api/v1/example")
         .map(data => data["username"])
         .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
 }
```

but i don't get any data, i even tried the filter

```
filter(data => data["id"] > 0)
```

but still fails, 
but if i just subscribe immediately like this i can retrieve the data

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this._http.get<Any[]>("api/v1/example")
         .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
 }
```

i use the stream in java as reference for this but i think they don't work the same, thank you in advance guys

Comment: when you check network `this._http.get<Any[]>("api/v1/example")` do you see 200 OK with the data as a response ?

Comment: check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khpht3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts now its iterating on your array

Comment: do you use the interceptor to add base URL? otherwise, you should add the base URL to your URL. Check out a network tab of dev tools

Comment: try `this._http.get<Any[]>("api/v1/example").pipe(
      map(d => {
        return d["username"];
      })
    ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: i edit my question. when i don't manipulate i just immediately subscribe i can retrieve those data

Comment: Just try by converting it to json: this._http.get<Any[]>("api/v1/example")
         .map(data => <any>data.json())
         .subscribe(data => console.log(data));

Comment: this will print whole array,,will not iterate over it

Comment: HttpClient send response on json format already

Comment: @rahul there is an error to your solution "the 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method 'this' of type Observable"

Comment: thanks @Rahul your solution works it seems that the problem earlier is on my import i imported map twice

Comment: can you create stackblitz for the same ?

Comment: @arnoldemzi please check your imports... I have used lettable operators.. so import map `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: I shall post this as answer ..kindly accept if it solves ur issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    this._http.get<Any[]>("api/v1/example").pipe(
          map(d => { return d["username"]; })
        ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

refer working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khpht3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)